# Why does a paracetamol tablet clean an iron

Tags: everyday-chemistry

If you burn some clothes on an iron and some residue sticks to it, rubbing a paracetamol tablet over it (while it's hot) surprisingly removes the residue and cleans the iron. Please explain why this happens.

Comment: paracetamol tablet decomposes to p-aminophenol almost quantitatively at hih temperatures, not sure how it cleans the iron. Perhaps the molten p-aminophenol solubilizes the synthetic charred polymers which are sticking on the iron's surface.

Comment: Many tablets contain silica (silicon dioxide) to avoid formation of large particles of the active drug. Silica is abrasive, so I think that silica is actually doing the magic. For comparison, you might try another tablet with silica in its composition: it should work the same way